# R, how to comare rows in several columns and create a new column based on the conditions?

Tags: r

I am working with R and I have a large dataset, 3-ish million rows, and four columns (id, line, time and date):

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(3454, 3453, 5546, 3453),
             datetime = c("2020/02/02 01:34:00","2020/02/03 20:24:10", 
             "2020/02/04 12:15:20", "2020/02/03 20:50:00"), 
             line = c(300, 400, 200, 100))

df$datetime <- as.POSIXct(df$datetime, format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")

df$time <- format(as.POSIXct(df$datetime, format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"),"%H:%M:%S")
df$date <- as.Date(df$date_time)
df <- df[,-2]

df
   id   line  time       date
1 3454  300 01:34:00 2020-02-02
2 3453  400 20:24:10 2020-02-04
3 5546  200 12:15:20 2020-02-04
4 3453  100 20:50:00 2020-02-04
```

I'm trying to create a new column by comparing every 2 rows with several conditions:

1. For the same value of id and date (column 1, 4) and
2. Not the same for line (column 2),
3. If the difference between time (column 3) is within 80 min,

the value of the new column would be 2, otherwise one.

Honestly, I couldn't figure out how to code this problem!

The desired result would be something as bellow:

```
df
   id   line  time       date     new
1 3454  300 01:34:00 2020-02-02    1
2 3453  400 20:24:10 2020-02-04    1
3 5546  200 12:15:20 2020-02-04    1
4 3453  100 20:50:00 2020-02-04    2
```

And the important thing is I want to delete the rows with the value of 2 in the new column and keep the others with the value of 1, and in this example, row 2 and 4 both meet all conditions I wrote before but, I would like to keep the earlier one based on the time (row 2) and just delete the row 4 with the later time!!

I'm really struggling with how to tackle this problem!
I would really appreciate any answer or suggestion :)

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah! I added some details

Comment: @akrun I tried to be more clear :)

Comment: @zoe your `as.POSIXct` step will fail without a `format`

Comment: I checked the structure of df and it shows what I want though

Comment: For the third and 4th, i find the difference to be more than 80 min

Comment: for the third one and the 4th, id and date are not the same so we can not pass to the other conditions for lines or times

Comment: @zoe try this `library(dplyr);library(lubridate); df %>% group_by(id, date) %>% mutate(Diff =  period_to_seconds(hms(time) - lag(hms(time)))/60) %>% ungroup %>% filter(Diff > 80|is.na(Diff))`

Comment: it gave me an error:

Comment: Error in initialize(value, ...) : 
  trying to get slot "year" from an object (class "Period") that is not an S4 object

Comment: You need to put the code you're using and the error you're getting [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64272699/edit).